# install npm workspace dependencies completely inside workspace

Tags: npm-workspaces

Is it possible to run an `npm ci --workspace=[some workspace]` command and confine the installed dependencies **inside that specific workspace directory**, instead of **bubbling up the shared ones to the project root node_modules folder**?

**Purpose**: I have a mono repo, and I would like to install the workspace dependencies, respect the root package-lock, and have them all in one place inside that one workspace. So I can copy the whole specific workspace directory and run the server from another location. Otherwise, I have to carefully merge the two node_module folders using a script.

Am I not thinking of the best way to approach this, and is this possible regardless?

EDIT: This seems to be exactly what I'm describing https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/287